# Formula field based on data input

Tags: formula-field

I need a formula field which I want to show percent completed based on how many fields have been updated.

So let's say I have fields A, B, C, D and our SDR has only updated three of the four fields, I want the formula field to return 75%. Is this possible?

Comment: Its possible.. refer the https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible and your formula should be like below.

Replace the `field(A__c, B__c, C__c & D__c) API Names` as per your org

```
If(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)),
       NOT(ISBLANK(B__c)),
       NOT(ISBLANK(C__c)),
       NOT(ISBLANK(D__c))),"100%",
       If(OR(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(B__c)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(C__C))),
             AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B__C)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(C__c)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(D__C))),
             AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C__C)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(D__c)),
                 NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)))),"75%",
            If(OR(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(B__c))),
                      
                  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(C__c))),
                      
                  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(D__c))),
                      
                  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(A__c))),
                      
                  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(D__c))),
                      
                  AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)),
                      NOT(ISBLANK(C__c)))
                      ),"50%",
                      if(OR(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A__C)),ISBLANK(B__c),ISBLANK(C__c),ISBLANK(D__c)),
                            AND(NOT(ISBLANK(B__C)),ISBLANK(C__c),ISBLANK(D__c),ISBLANK(A__c)),
                            AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C__C)),ISBLANK(D__c),ISBLANK(A__c),ISBLANK(B__c)),
                            AND(NOT(ISBLANK(D__C)),ISBLANK(A__c),ISBLANK(B__c),ISBLANK(C__c)),),"25%",""
                      
                        )
            )
                 
        )
  )
```

IF

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given value if
> true and another value if false.
>
> Use: IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false) and replace
> logical_test with the expression you want evaluated; replace
> value_if_true with the value you want returned if the expression is
> true; replace value_if_false with the value you want returned if the
> expression is false.

AND

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE
> response if one or more values are false.
>
> Use the && (AND) function as an alternative to the operator.
>
> Use: AND(logical1,logical2,...) and replace logical1,logical2,... with
> the values that you want evaluated.

OR

> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns TRUE if any
> expression is true. Returns FALSE if all expressions are false.
>
> Use this function as an alternative to the operator || (OR)
>
> Use: OR(logical1, logical2...) and replace any number of logical
> references with the expressions you want evaluated.

Refer the [Formula Operators and Functions by Context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5)